# Array out of bounds Exception?

Tags: java, arrays

Ok so this for a lab in college.Trying to take in integers the user enters,put them in an array and print them out.

Im getting an error when I try to compile.

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
    at Lab3.main(Lab3.java:12)

```
public class Lab3 {


public static void main(String[] args) {


int[] First = {};

for(int i=0;i<First.length;i++)
{
    First[i] = (int)(Math.random() *10 +1); 
    System.out.print(First[i] + " ");
}
for(int i=0;i<First.length;i++)
{






    if (First[i]%2==0)
    {

        System.out.println("Even numbers are:"+First[i]);
    }


}

for(int i=0;i<First.length;i+=2)    
{

    if (First[i]%2==0)
    {

        System.out.println("Even numbers are:"+First[i]);
    }



}

for(int i=0;i<First.length;i++)
{
        int temp = First[i];
        First[i] = First[First.length - i - 1];
        First[First.length - i - 1] = temp;
        System.out.println("Reverse is:"+temp);
}


System.out.println("First is:"+First[0]);
System.out.println("First is:"+First[9]);




}
```

}

Comment: You initialize an empty array (0 fields) and then attempt to access its first field (index 0).

Comment: You can also use an arrayList it is more flexible

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By doing

```
int[] First = {};
// is the same as
int[] First = new int[0];
```

you're creating an array with 0 elements. You then try to access the first element.

```
System.out.println("First is:"+First[0]); // access first element of empty array?
```

Since you have no elements, how can you access them? Create an array with 10 elements

```
int[] First = new int[10];
```

if you want a static collection (not resizable) or use a `List` implementation to have a dynamic collection (resizable).

---

Java naming conventions state that variables should start with a lowercase alphabetic character. Use `camelCase`.

Comment: the `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` doesn't happen in that line, as it's protected by a loop. The exception is thrown almost at the end of the code, in the `println` statement.

Answer (score 2):

```
int[] First = {};
```

intializes a 0-length array.

`First[0]` doesn't exist. Mention the length as a part of declaration or later.

`First = new int[10]; //creates an array of 10 ints`

Note that above will throw the same exception on `First[11]`

If you are unsure of the size you can use an [ArrayList](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&ved=0CDYQFjAB&url=http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html&ei=l5xBUvTkJIPQrQeJvIDIDQ&usg=AFQjCNEIhLDKau6EelJxSOf936K_NKAdng&sig2=j-hSxK_pShmbP-DzuDCvvg&bvm=bv.52434380,d.bmk) instead.

```
List<Integer> first = new ArrayList<Integer>();
first.add((int)Math.random() *10 +1);
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use a List instead, because your array will grow in time. That's why you can't access First[i], because your array is initialized with an empty array(and will stay like that forever). You can also initialize your array with some elements(not your use case) or using new with an initial capacity.

Comment: Thanks! Will know for next time.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a List instead, because your array will grow in time.